# Getting an instance of a running servlet

Tags: gwt, servlets

I am using GWT and I have a problem.
I want to access the running instance of the servlet declared in web.xml.
How can I do this??
I need to have a main running in the same JVM as the servlet. I have an interface between the main class that the servlet implements. This interface allows the main to fill a queue in the servlet.

Need help

Thank you

Comment: To restate Bozho's answer: you're looking for a solution in the wrong direction. If you elaborate in detail the functional requirement for which you thought that this is the right solution, then we may be able to post a more detailed answer.

Comment: I'm working on a MVC project. The controller needs to fill up a queue on the server. So it either has to start one(another post) or it needs a running instance.

Answer (score 1):

It is usual to create a special servlet for configuration/utility actions, for such cases.

The shared data is in that case placed as [`ServletContext`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) attributes (via the `setAttribute(..)` and `getAttribute(..)` methods)

Comment: How would you use a ServletContext?

Comment: `getServletContext().setAttribute(..)` Check  the javadoc.